# Keep only the first 8 characters in a line in notepad++

Tags: regex, notepad++

I'm having troubles on keeping the first 8 characters in Notepad++.

I have a list like this :

```
johndoe2.21test
markdoetesting.new
marvin213.jo.hn
abcd1234.dcba
```

And I want a output like this:

```
johndoe2
markdoet
marvin21
abcd1234
```

Can you point me in the right direction ?

Comment: Replace `^(.{8}).*` with `\1` in regex mode.

Answer (score 14):

You could use the [column select](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/features/column-mode-editing.html) feature for this.

- Use Alt + Shift + Arrow keys to select only the first eight characters.
- Once you select, copy it and paste it elsewhere.

You can also use Find and Replace in Regular Expression mode.

- Use Find/Replace feature.
- Select Regex Search Mode.
- In Find box enter this `^(.{8}).*`
- In Replace box enter this `\1`
- Click on Replace All.